# The modification date of Drive files change when Google Apps Script move a file to other folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am moving file this way:

```
var idOriginFolder = 'ABCDEFG12345abcdefg';
var originFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(idOriginFolder);
var destinationFolder = DriveApp.createFolder('New Folder');
var searchString = '"'+idOriginFolder+'" in parents'
var foundFiles = DriveApp.searchFiles(searchString);
while (foundFiles.hasNext()){
 var file = foundFiles.next();
 destinationFolder.addFile(file);
 originFolder.removeFile(file);
}
```

The files are moved correctly, but the modification date of every one moved file is changed to script execution date. Do you know any way to avoid this? When I move files throught of the Web Interface of Google Drive this not happen.

Comment: Does this also happen if you use the Drive REST API (i.e. via the Advanced Service `Drive`) to change the file's `parents` array? https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/parents https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/patch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, the modification date of files is not changed by moving using Drive API v3. In your question, when the files were moved using DriveApp, the modification date was changed. I think that DriveApp uses Drive API v2. So I investigated this, because I was interested in this situation.

For Drive API v2

- It was found that when the files were moved using `drive.files.update` and `drive.files.patch`, the modification date was changed.

For Drive API v3

- It was found that when the files were moved using `drive.files.update`, the modification date was **NOT** changed.

#### Sample script :

The sample script for using Drive API v3 is as follows.

```
var idOriginFolder = 'ABCDEFG12345abcdefg';
var destinationFolder = DriveApp.createFolder('New Folder').getId();
var searchString = '"'+idOriginFolder+'" in parents'
var foundFiles = DriveApp.searchFiles(searchString);
var requests = [];
while (foundFiles.hasNext()){
  var file = foundFiles.next();
  requests.push({
    url: "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + file.getId() + "?addParents=" + destinationFolder + "&removeParents=" + idOriginFolder,
    method: "patch",
    headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
  });
}
var res = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(requests);
Logger.log(res)
```

#### Note :

- From these results, it is considered that moving files by Web Interface may be due to Drive API v3.
- This is a simple sample script. So if you want to move a lot of files, I recommend to use the Batching Requests.

#### Reference :

- [Files: update for Drive API v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/update)
- [Files: patch for Drive API v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/patch)
- [Files: update for Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/update)
- [Batching Requests](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/batch)

If this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.

Comment: Excellent! Using this method the code working and is pretty more fast.

Comment: @evilside Welcome. I'm glad your issue was solved. Also I could study from your question. Thank you, too.