# How do I add a shared file to a specified folder without modifying date or by fields?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am programmatically adding shared files to folders based on the owner, but when I do that it changes the Modified By user and the Modified Date. Is there a way to add it to a folder without this changing the files data?

```
    if (type == "A"){//add to "A" Folder
      destA_folder.addFile(file);
    }else{    //add to B Folder
      destB_folder.addFile(file);
    }
```

Comment: Please search for existing questions before asking: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50005351/the-modification-date-of-drive-files-change-when-google-apps-script-move-a-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The modification date of Drive files change when Google Apps Script move a file to other folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50005351/the-modification-date-of-drive-files-change-when-google-apps-script-move-a-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it using Drive API v3. When the folder is added using DriveApp and Drive API v2, the Modified By user and the Modified Date are updated. But at Drive API v3, those are not updated. This sample script uses `update` of Drive API v3.

#### Sample script :

```
var fileId = "### file ID ###"; // Please input file ID.

var orgFolder = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getParents().next().getId();
if (type == "A"){//add to "A" Folder
  var dstFolderA = '### destination folder ID ###'; // Please input destination folder ID.
  var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + fileId + "?addParents=" + dstFolderA + "&removeParents=" + orgFolder;
}else{    //add to B Folder
  var dstFolderB = '### destination folder ID ###'; // Please input destination folder ID.
  var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + fileId + "?addParents=" + dstFolderB + "&removeParents=" + orgFolder;
}
var params = {
  method: "patch",
  headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
  muteHttpExceptions: true,
};
var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
Logger.log(res)
```

#### Note :

- From your script, it seems that you want to only add a parent to the file. In this case, the file has 2 parents. If you want to move the file, please remove the original parents.
- In this sample script, the original parent is removed. If you don't want to remove it, please remove `"&removeParents=" + orgFolder` from the script.

#### References :

- [Files: update for Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/update)

If this was not what you want, I'm sorry.

Comment: For duplicates, please flag as duplicate! Surely you remembered answering this very same question yesterday :D

Comment: @tehhowch OK, can I set the flag of duplicates, leaving this answer for solving owner's issue?